# Error in the AWS console (browser) 'The security token included in the request is invalid' during the Cloudfront distribution creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

So first of all - my `c:\Users\user_name\.aws\` has just the default section with proper single profile keys AND also cleared browser cache.

I am trying to create Cloudfront distribution in my current account but see this error even without selecting custom certificate (error stays even after certificate selection)

[image]

In the Network tab I see that that's the 403 result of POST call to https://iam.amazonaws.com/ with this parameters

```
Action: ListServerCertificates
MaxItems: 1000
PathPrefix: %2Fcloudfront%2F
Version: 2010-05-08
```

Response:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://iam.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-08/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>c98cd3ca-5a2e-45fe-bf81-27ba643429b6</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: Your web browser session doesnt use the credentials stored on disk (they are used by the CLI and SDKs). Issue is going to be related to the IAM user your logging into the console. The error implies your user is missing the IAM permission `acm:ListCertificates`

Comment: How can it be? I am logged as root user

Comment: Have you tried logging out and then logging back in?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post - yes, cleared the cache as well as incognito mode

Comment: I have the same thing. I have tried deleting the certificate and reissuing it. And as well, when I totally remove everything from the distribution settings, it still has the error.

Comment: @Rickaroo yep, the same - deleted the cert, deleted everything via my terraform, reassuring myself new cert and same error

Comment: for what it's worth, my error is still there, but the distribution is functioning as expected with my custom domain name using the certificate (*.mydomainname.com) that shows is in error because of the "security token included in the request is invalid". I'm just treating it as a ghost error that aws either doesn't know about or doesn't care about. (Note: I'm logged in as root user as well and have logged out and back in.)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this policy with IAM user or Role to resolve the error:

```
{

    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:ListServerCertificates",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```